# Unable to install OMNET++ 4.6 on WIndows 10

Tags: windows, installation, omnet++

I want to use OMNET++ for running libPTP repository. It uses the 4.6 version, but I am not able to install this version using ./configure option. However, with similar steps can install latest version 5.5. Following is the problem which I am getting.

[image: Installation problem]

Please let me know if anyone else experienced a similar problem?

Comment: Try to turn off you antivirus real-time checking.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the ZIP file is correct (check the CRC of the file and see if it matches with the one published on the website). Also make sure to use a decent ZIP extract app. The built-in ZIP extractor in Windows is known to leave out some files every once. Also turning off virus checking on the folder/file is good idea as suggested by @jerzy-d